# Rails3 incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 in html mailer template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, actionmailer

I send a text e-mail alright, but the html version of the same generates a

```
  'incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8'
```

error message, although both my controller and mailer have a '#encoding: utf-8' as a first line...